# How to get the twitter card data form twitter

Tags: twitter

How we get the twitter card data from twitter when we get the twits.
my code is

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
                $page_html = new DomDocument();

                $ch = curl_init();

                $timeout = 500;

                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);  
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 3);     
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);

                $data = curl_exec($ch);
                curl_close($ch);

            if(!empty($data)){

                $page_html->loadHTML($data);

            }
```

Comment: I don't understand the question - your code has no references to Twitter in it so can you explain what you are trying to do more clearly?

Comment: Can i get the twitter card form twitter API http://prntscr.com/gb2myt

Comment: No the card data is not available in the API and is rendered server side by the Twitter native client apps.

Comment: So please can you help me how we get the twitter card data

Comment: It is not possible to get Twitter Card data from the API.

Comment: Any type how we get the twitter card

Comment: Have you found a way to get the twitter card ? @JitendraPrajapati

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get Twitter Card data from the API.